# Django query filter a set of data

Tags: django, filter, character-encoding

if a have a query like

```
    following = Relations.objects.filter(initiated_by = request.user)
```

in which i'm having all the users followed by the currently logged in user,
and i want to display those user's blog posts. Using a query like:

```
    blog = New.objects.filter(created_by = following)
```

it only shows me the blog posts of the user with the id = 1 (though the currently logged in user doesn't actually follow him)
in template i have :

```
{% for object in blog %}
<a href='/accounts/profile_view/{{object.created_by}}/'> {{object.created_by}}</a> <br /> 
{{object.post}}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter()` returns a collection, not an occurence. Thus, I'd say problem is that second query should be

```
blog = New.objects.filter(created_by__in = following)
```

Comment: strangely, it did not output what i want. the query i want to achieve is something like: select * from new,follow 
where created_by = user 
or 
created_by = (select * from new where following = user)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is sql's OR for django ORM, so I'd probably fall back to using two queries.

Comment: You can do 'OR' with Django by using the 'Q' object that is in django.db.models (see my comment on my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler :

```
bloc = New.objects.filter(created_by__initiated_by = request.user)
```

But that feels strange to me... are you sure of your model design ?

Comment: in brief, i want to 'translate' a query like that: select * from new,follow 
where created_by = user 
or 
created_by = (select * from new where following = user)

Comment: so maybe you need to use the django 'Q' object which allows to make 'OR' queries :

    from django.db.models import Q

    MyModel.objects.filter(Q(some_field = something) | Q(some_other_field = foobar))